# Duplicated Play Store app fails to instantiate

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Compiled an APK and tested it successfully on my device, tried it through the Google Play Store and it stops working immediately. This app is a copy of an existing app, since you cannot have the same package name twice I simply renamed the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml, compiled it, tested it and then uploaded it to the Play Store.

I do not understand why the app works when I copy it to a device but the same app fails when loaded through the Play Store. I generated a crash report which I accessed from the Play Store Developer Console. If anyone has experience of successfully duplicating apps on the Store then your help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte.WalletApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte.WalletApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte-1/lib/arm, /data/app/de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:680)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte.WalletApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte-1/lib/arm, /data/app/de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1005)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:670)
... 9 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.schildbach.wallet.artbyte.WalletApplication
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception says that build is failed due to class not found on dex path list. Build the apk by cleaning the project and also recompile the native code using the ndk-build command. Then try it on the local device and then upload to play store.

Answer (score 0):

The package name in AndroidManifest.xml is often also used for the code base, e.g. as class name of the activities. If you only rename the package name but leave the Java/dex code unchanged Android will not be able to find some classes as you already have noticed.

Check the AndroidManifest.xml for package relative class names (those that start with a `.`) and prepend the old package name:

## Example

```
Old package name: org.example.myapp
Old activity name: <activity android:name=".MyActivity" ..>

New package name: com.example.newappname
New activity name: <activity android:name="org.example.myapp.MyActivity" ..>
```